# I have a problem using my project showing only json format in asp.net core. The values are just null. What is happening in this case?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core

This is the code for migration and models classes generated:

[image: My Command Prompt]

[image: My Results]

## Ideas Code 001

````
    ```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

        namespace IDSCyberProject.Models
        {
    public partial class Ideas
    {
        public double? R1pa1vh { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm1v { get; set; }
        public double? R1pa2vh { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm2v { get; set; }
        public double? R1pa3vh { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm3v { get; set; }
        public double? R1pa4ih { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm4i { get; set; }
        public double? R1pa5ih { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm5i { get; set; }
        public double? R1pa6ih { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm6i { get; set; }
        public double? R1pa7vh { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm7v { get; set; }
        public double? R1pa8vh { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm8v { get; set; }
        public double? R1pa9vh { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm9v { get; set; }
        public double? R1pa10ih { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm10i { get; set; }
        public double? R1pa11ih { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm11i { get; set; }
        public double? R1pa12ih { get; set; }
        public double? R1pm12i { get; set; }
        public double? R1f { get; set; }
        public double? R1df { get; set; }
        public double? R1paz { get; set; }
        public double? R1pazh { get; set; }
        public double? R1s { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa1vh { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm1v { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa2vh { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm2v { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa3vh { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm3v { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa4ih { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm4i { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa5ih { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm5i { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa6ih { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm6i { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa7vh { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm7v { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa8vh { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm8v { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa9vh { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm9v { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa10ih { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm10i { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa11ih { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm11i { get; set; }
        public double? R2pa12ih { get; set; }
        public double? R2pm12i { get; set; }
        public double? R2f { get; set; }
        public double? R2df { get; set; }
        public double? R2paz { get; set; }
        public double? R2pazh { get; set; }
        public double? R2s { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa1vh { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm1v { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa2vh { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm2v { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa3vh { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm3v { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa4ih { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm4i { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa5ih { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm5i { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa6ih { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm6i { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa7vh { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm7v { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa8vh { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm8v { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa9vh { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm9v { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa10ih { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm10i { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa11ih { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm11i { get; set; }
        public double? R3pa12ih { get; set; }
        public double? R3pm12i { get; set; }
        public double? R3f { get; set; }
        public double? R3df { get; set; }
        public double? R3paz { get; set; }
        public double? R3pazh { get; set; }
        public double? R3s { get; set; }
        public double? R4pa1vh { get; set; }
        public double? R4pm1v { get; set; }
        public double? R4pa2vh { get; set; }
        public double? R4pm2v { get; set; }
        public double? R4pa3vh { get; set; }
        public double? R4pm3v { get; set; }
        public double? R4pa4ih { get; set; }
        public double? R4pm4i { get; set; }
        public double? R4pa5ih { get; set; }
````

## Startup.cs Code 002

```
     using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
     using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
     using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
     using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
     using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
     using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;



namespace IDSCyberProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        /*
        [Obsolete]
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            var environment = Configuration["ApplicationSettings:Environment"];
        }*/  


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            //services.AddControllersWithViews();


            //services.Configure<Models.AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));

            //For ASP.NET Core 2.1 and 2.2
            //In the ConfigureServices method of the Startup class, Set options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false; as follows
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential 
                // cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                // requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;

            });



            services.AddMvc()
                    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues.ToString();
                    });

            //services.AddRazorPages();
        }  



                // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request 
            pipeline.
                      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Usage", "MVC1005:Cannot use 
           UseMvc with Endpoint Routing.", Justification = "<Pending>")]
           public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
                  {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            /*else
            {
                //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                //app.UseHsts();
            }*/


            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            //app.UseMvc();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            /*app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });*/


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                //endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

## Program.cs Code 003 #

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

    namespace IDSCyberProject
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }

            public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    });
        }
    }
```

## DBIdsContext.cs Code 003 #

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

    namespace IDSCyberProject.Models
    {
        public partial class dbidsContext : DbContext
        {
            public dbidsContext()
            {
            }

            public dbidsContext(DbContextOptions<dbidsContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {
            }

            public virtual DbSet<Efmigrationshistory> Efmigrationshistory { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Ideas> Ideas { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Testids1> Testids1 { get; set; }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
                {
    #warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
                    optionsBuilder.UseMySql("Server=localhost;Database=dbids;Uid=admin;Pwd=P@ssw0rd;");
                }
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Efmigrationshistory>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasKey(e => e.MigrationId)
                        .HasName("PRIMARY");

                    entity.ToTable("__efmigrationshistory");

                    entity.Property(e => e.MigrationId).HasColumnType("varchar(95)");

                    entity.Property(e => e.ProductVersion)
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("varchar(32)");
                });

                modelBuilder.Entity<Ideas>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasNoKey();

                    entity.ToTable("ideas");

                    entity.Property(e => e.ControlPanelLog1).HasColumnName("control_panel_log1").HasColumnType("double");

                    entity.Property(e => e.ControlPanelLog2).HasColumnName("control_panel_log2");

                    entity.Property(e => e.ControlPanelLog3).HasColumnName("control_panel_log3");

                    entity.Property(e => e.ControlPanelLog4).HasColumnName("control_panel_log4");

                    entity.Property(e => e.Filename)
                        .HasColumnName("filename")
                        .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                    entity.Property(e => e.Marker)
                        .HasColumnName("marker")
                        .HasColumnType("varchar(100)");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1df).HasColumnName("R1DF").HasColumnType("double");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1f).HasColumnName("R1F");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa10ih).HasColumnName("R1PA10IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa11ih).HasColumnName("R1PA11IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa12ih).HasColumnName("R1PA12IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa1vh).HasColumnName("R1PA1VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa2vh).HasColumnName("R1PA2VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa3vh).HasColumnName("R1PA3VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa4ih).HasColumnName("R1PA4IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa5ih).HasColumnName("R1PA5IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa6ih).HasColumnName("R1PA6IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa7vh).HasColumnName("R1PA7VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa8vh).HasColumnName("R1PA8VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pa9vh).HasColumnName("R1PA9VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1paz).HasColumnName("R1PAZ");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pazh).HasColumnName("R1PAZH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm10i).HasColumnName("R1PM10I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm11i).HasColumnName("R1PM11I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm12i).HasColumnName("R1PM12I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm1v).HasColumnName("R1PM1V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm2v).HasColumnName("R1PM2V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm3v).HasColumnName("R1PM3V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm4i).HasColumnName("R1PM4I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm5i).HasColumnName("R1PM5I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm6i).HasColumnName("R1PM6I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm7v).HasColumnName("R1PM7V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm8v).HasColumnName("R1PM8V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1pm9v).HasColumnName("R1PM9V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R1s).HasColumnName("R1S");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2df).HasColumnName("R2DF");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2f).HasColumnName("R2F");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa10ih).HasColumnName("R2PA10IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa11ih).HasColumnName("R2PA11IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa12ih).HasColumnName("R2PA12IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa1vh).HasColumnName("R2PA1VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa2vh).HasColumnName("R2PA2VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa3vh).HasColumnName("R2PA3VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa4ih).HasColumnName("R2PA4IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa5ih).HasColumnName("R2PA5IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa6ih).HasColumnName("R2PA6IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa7vh).HasColumnName("R2PA7VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa8vh).HasColumnName("R2PA8VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pa9vh).HasColumnName("R2PA9VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2paz).HasColumnName("R2PAZ");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pazh).HasColumnName("R2PAZH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm10i).HasColumnName("R2PM10I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm11i).HasColumnName("R2PM11I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm12i).HasColumnName("R2PM12I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm1v).HasColumnName("R2PM1V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm2v).HasColumnName("R2PM2V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm3v).HasColumnName("R2PM3V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm4i).HasColumnName("R2PM4I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm5i).HasColumnName("R2PM5I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm6i).HasColumnName("R2PM6I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm7v).HasColumnName("R2PM7V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm8v).HasColumnName("R2PM8V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2pm9v).HasColumnName("R2PM9V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R2s).HasColumnName("R2S");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3df).HasColumnName("R3DF");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3f).HasColumnName("R3F");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa10ih).HasColumnName("R3PA10IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa11ih).HasColumnName("R3PA11IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa12ih).HasColumnName("R3PA12IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa1vh).HasColumnName("R3PA1VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa2vh).HasColumnName("R3PA2VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa3vh).HasColumnName("R3PA3VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa4ih).HasColumnName("R3PA4IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa5ih).HasColumnName("R3PA5IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa6ih).HasColumnName("R3PA6IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa7vh).HasColumnName("R3PA7VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa8vh).HasColumnName("R3PA8VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pa9vh).HasColumnName("R3PA9VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3paz).HasColumnName("R3PAZ");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pazh).HasColumnName("R3PAZH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm10i).HasColumnName("R3PM10I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm11i).HasColumnName("R3PM11I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm12i).HasColumnName("R3PM12I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm1v).HasColumnName("R3PM1V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm2v).HasColumnName("R3PM2V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm3v).HasColumnName("R3PM3V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm4i).HasColumnName("R3PM4I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm5i).HasColumnName("R3PM5I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm6i).HasColumnName("R3PM6I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm7v).HasColumnName("R3PM7V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm8v).HasColumnName("R3PM8V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3pm9v).HasColumnName("R3PM9V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R3s).HasColumnName("R3S");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4df).HasColumnName("R4DF");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4f).HasColumnName("R4F");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa10ih).HasColumnName("R4PA10IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa11ih).HasColumnName("R4PA11IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa12ih).HasColumnName("R4PA12IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa1vh).HasColumnName("R4PA1VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa2vh).HasColumnName("R4PA2VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa3vh).HasColumnName("R4PA3VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa4ih).HasColumnName("R4PA4IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa5ih).HasColumnName("R4PA5IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa6ih).HasColumnName("R4PA6IH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa7vh).HasColumnName("R4PA7VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa8vh).HasColumnName("R4PA8VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pa9vh).HasColumnName("R4PA9VH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4paz).HasColumnName("R4PAZ");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pazh).HasColumnName("R4PAZH");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm10i).HasColumnName("R4PM10I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm11i).HasColumnName("R4PM11I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm12i).HasColumnName("R4PM12I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm1v).HasColumnName("R4PM1V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm2v).HasColumnName("R4PM2V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm3v).HasColumnName("R4PM3V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm4i).HasColumnName("R4PM4I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm5i).HasColumnName("R4PM5I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm6i).HasColumnName("R4PM6I");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm7v).HasColumnName("R4PM7V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm8v).HasColumnName("R4PM8V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4pm9v).HasColumnName("R4PM9V");

                    entity.Property(e => e.R4s).HasColumnName("R4S");

                    entity.Property(e => e.Relay1Log).HasColumnName("relay1_log");

                    entity.Property(e => e.Relay2Log).HasColumnName("relay2_log");

                    entity.Property(e => e.Relay3Log).HasColumnName("relay3_log");

                    entity.Property(e => e.Relay4Log).HasColumnName("relay4_log");

                    entity.Property(e => e.SnortLog1).HasColumnName("snort_log1");

                    entity.Property(e => e.SnortLog2).HasColumnName("snort_log2");

                    entity.Property(e => e.SnortLog3).HasColumnName("snort_log3");

                    entity.Property(e => e.SnortLog4).HasColumnName("snort_log4");
                });

                modelBuilder.Entity<Testids1>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasNoKey();

                    entity.ToTable("testids1");

                    entity.Property(e => e.ColumnA).HasColumnType("int(11)");

                    entity.Property(e => e.ColumnB).HasColumnType("int(11)");

                    entity.Property(e => e.ColumnC).HasColumnType("int(11)");

                    entity.Property(e => e.ColumnD).HasColumnType("int(11)");
                });

                OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
            }

            partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

## Controller

This controller was

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace IDSProject_DS_29_10_19.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]


    public class Ideas : ControllerBase
    {

        public Ideas(ILogger<Ideas> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        private readonly ILogger<Ideas> _logger;


        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Models.Ideas> Get()
        {
            //var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(index => new Models.Ideas { Filename = 11 }).ToArray();
        }


    }
```

The issue is that in the code is showed the values in NULL in my URL code. How to solve this issue if the database is having numeric values, where the most values are of type "double".

Comment: describe what you expect to see and show code that should generate that.  (You should probably remove your connection string too... I know it's localhost, but...)

Comment: I hope to see all the values instead of null from mysql database on localhost.

Comment: maybe I missed it, but I don't see a query here... post your .cs file.

Comment: You only provide the configuration about your project.But how did you generate the json?Please share your more detailed code.

Comment: My controller class in cs code:



namespace IDSCyberProject.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]

    public class Ideas : ControllerBase
    {



        private readonly ILogger<Ideas> _logger;

        public Ideas(ILogger<Ideas> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Models.Ideas> Get()
        {
            //var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new Models.Ideas { Filename = 2 }).ToList();


        }
    }


}

Comment: GenericArguments[0], 'IDSProject_DS_29_10_19.Migrations.dbidsContext', on 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type 'TContext'.
HOW to solve it?

Comment: It is showing just NULL values for the json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by resolving the issue with the code bellow:

```
         var x = _db.Ideas.Where(a => a.Filename == 11).Skip(10).Take(2).ToList();
        //return Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(_db.Ideas.Where(a => a.Filename == 11).ToList();

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
```